# Using an alias when using NFS shares

Tags: linux, freebsd, nfs

When using Samba, I can use an alias which can pretty much point to any directory.  E.g. an alias called `videos` pointing to

```
/mystuff/here/anotherfolder/anotheronehere/oops/myvideosfolder
```

Is something similar available for NFS shares?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolic link to the target directory.  To follow your example:

```
ln -s /mystuff/here/anotherfolder/anotheronehere/oops/myvideosfolder ~/videos
```

Comment: This will not work because nfs will follow the symlink and export the location that the symlink is linked to, not the location of the symlink itself.